# How to restore rubber dome keyboard membrane springiness?

Tags: keyboard, restore

I got an used ThinkOutside Stowaway Bluetooth keyboard and would like to restore it, as it's a beautiful thing, especially the folding mechanism, but a lot of the keys are stuck and don't spring back up.

I think it's just because the rubber of the membrane is old. If I take the keys out, I see that the key's dome is stuck in the "down" position, and if I take tweezers, pull it back up, and press it back a couple times, it starts working again - for a while, until I close the keyboard anyway.

My question is then, is there any way to restore the membrane to its original springiness? Some oils I could rub on it, heat treatment maybe?

edit: My question is not about a mechanical keyboard, but about one with a rubber dome membrane, the ThinkOutside Stowaway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I repair a mechanical keyboard?](https://superuser.com/questions/190804/how-do-i-repair-a-mechanical-keyboard)

Comment: @harrymc Very much not, because that question is about mechanical keyboards.

Comment: That post treats all kinds.

Comment: 1. The linked thread does address your type of keyboard, so it's a duplicate.  2. The advice there for your type of keyboard sucks.  If the problem is just accumulated crud, yes, it might help.  But that loss of springiness is usually due to fatigue of the material, and there's no good way to repair that unless you can get a new membrane sheet for that keyboard (and I'm not aware that the manufacturers sell them as a repair part).

Comment: @fixer1234 right, "wipe it down with distilled water" doesn't exactly help my problem, there is no dirt or crud accumulated; and the "springiness" or flexibility isn't mentioned at all :[